# $ ps aux k -rss の表示結果について

Tags: mysql, centos

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・以前は普通に表示されていたWebサイト表示が、最近とくに遅くなっているので、原因を知りたい

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx
・MySQL5.7
・PHP7
・複数Webサイト(バーチャルドメイン)

---

**プロセスに問題があるかと思い下記コマンドを打ったのですが、下記結果から分かることはありますか？**
・MySQLのCPU占有率が50％を超えていますが、ここからさらに調べるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・php-fpmが複数表示されていますが、バーチャルドメインの数だけ処理が走っているということですか？
・nginxのCPU占有率が0.0なのはなぜですか？
・そもそも、Webサイトの表示とメモリ消費量に関係はありますか？

```
$ ps aux k -rss | head -n 10
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql     1461 54.9 10.8 2343868 109876 ?      Sl    2018 59511:59 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
nginx    23998  0.0  2.5 1741908 26048 ?       Sl    2月08  12:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    23991  0.0  2.4 1748572 24704 ?       Sl    2月08  13:07 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    20198  0.0  2.2 1754852 22580 ?       Sl    2月01  16:18 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    23993  0.0  1.9 1752084 20076 ?       Sl    2月08  13:08 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    23992  0.0  1.9 1750204 19956 ?       Sl    2月08  13:12 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    23996  0.0  1.9 1747384 19844 ?       Sl    2月08  12:40 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    13729  0.0  1.8 1609660 18512 ?       Sl    2月17   8:41 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    23990  0.0  1.8 1739940 18340 ?       Sl    2月08  12:19 php-fpm: pool www
```

Comment: タイトルと本文とで質問内容が一貫していないような印象です。実行したコマンドはメモリでソートをかけてますが、チェックしてるのはCPU占有率になってますよね？ (最終的にはCPUとメモリ等から総合的に判断すべきですが) / また、プロセスが使用するリソースは刻一刻と変化しますが、psコマンドは瞬間の結果を表示してる点は注意しましょう。 / 実メモリはどれ位あって、そのうち使用・空きがどれ位なのかの情報も必要かなと。

Comment: 「実メモリはどれ位あって、そのうち使用・空きがどれ位なのかの情報」はどうやって調べるのですか？

Comment: `free`コマンドや`top`コマンド等で使用メモリ(と実メモリ)を確認することができます。

Comment: freeコマンドやtopコマンドで検索したら色々見つかりました。検索キーワード自体が良く分からなかったので参考になりました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql に対して slow query が実行されているような気がします。 slow query log の設定をオンにして、その内容を確認するのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 特に気になる点はない感じでしょうか？ それではMySQLパフォーマンスチューニングに取り組んでみようと思います